# Flutter what is the difference between creating state in different manner?

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, we can use any of them to create our `StatefulWidget`. Like:

1:

```
class MyClass extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyClassState();
}
```

2:

```
class MyClass extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<MyClass> createState() => MyClassState();
}
```

3:

```
class MyClass extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  MyClassState createState() => MyClassState();
}
```

What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference at all between them, because in all of these snippets `createState` type is either `State<StatefulWidget>` or one of its subclasses. Which correctly overrides `createState`.